# How to color code cells in a row based on frequency of values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight the cell based on the frequency of values. If you see below example 400 is repeated more often , so i highlighted as Green, the second frequent is 300 which i wish to high light as yellow and rest as blue. Can someone help me with the formula. I tried to find help in web , i could not get any close answer

sample excel data

```
Table_Name  NA_DATA_CNT EU_DATA_CNT APAC_DATA_CNT   EMEA_DATA_CNT   REST
A   400 400 300 300 200
```

[image]

Comment: You can set up [conditional formatting using custom formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f), and simply find an appropriate formula for frequency as is appropriate for your data (for example, with [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

- All cells formatted blue color per standard
- Select range, in below example it's `B2:F4` and apply new formatting rule for **most common value**:

  ```
  =B2=MODE($B2:$F2)
  ```
- Choose to format green and apply.
- Repeat the second step, but apply formula for **second most common value**:

  ```
  =B2=MODE(IF($B2:$F2<>MODE($B2:$F2),$B2:$F2,""))
  ```
- Choose to format as yellow and apply
- Confirm, and in my example the result would look like:

[image]

**EDIT**

To assist on this matter:

> *"One more help i need, now we have marked the most frequent values green, if there are values which is 1.5% more or less than the more frequent value, i need to mark it yellow and rest as blue."*

You can change the second conditional formatting rule formula to:

```
=AND(B2>=0.985*MODE($B2:$F2),B2<=1.015*MODE($B2:$F2))
```

[image]

Comment: One more help i need, now we have marked the most frequent values green, if there are values which is 1.5% more or less than the more frequent value, i need to mark it yellow and rest as blue. Can you please help. I really need it @JvdV